# Matcher for regex compiled from Strings misses group

Tags: java, regex

This must be something simple but I cannot get my head around it.

I have a String "qu'il".

I also have a String `pttrns` containing patterns that should be checked against, something like this:

`pttrns = "^(([dcjlmnstDCJLNMST]'|[Qq]u'|[Jj]usqu'|[Ll]orsqu'))(.+)$";`

I construct my pattern like this: `p = Pattern.compile("^(" + p + ")(.+)$");`

Now I try to match:

`m = p.matcher("qu'il");`

I would expect three groups:

- 0: qu'il
- 1: qu'
- 2: il

Instead, I get

- 0: qu'il
- 1: qu'il
- 2: qu'
- 3: qu'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove unnecessary capturing groups. And also you don't need to add `^(` before a regex which is already anchored.

```
pttrns = "^([dcjlmnstDCJLNMST]'|[Qq]u'|[Jj]usqu'|[Ll]orsqu')(.+)$";
p = Pattern.compile(pttrns);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wB8eK1/1)